# ActiveRecord doesn't create tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm trying to use ActiveRecord and rails migration in a non-rails project. I installed the [standalone_migrations](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations) gem and it seems to work. To test, I created two migration with

```
rake db:new_migration name=users
rake db:new_migration name=logins
```

Here are my migration files:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string    :full_name,   :null => false

      # Database authenticable
      t.string    :username,           :null => false, :default => '', :unique => true
      t.string    :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ''
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

class CreateLogins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :logins do |t|
      t.integer   :user_id,       :null => false
      t.datetime  :logged_in_at,  :null => false
      t.datetime  :logged_out_at, :null => false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :logins
  end
end
```

I then ran `rake db:migrate` and it seems to work:

```
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0020s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0020s) ===========================================

==  CreateLogins: migrating ===================================================
-- create_table(:logins)
   -> 0.0020s
==  CreateLogins: migrated (0.0020s) ==========================================
```

I have a `db/migrate` folder and a `db/config.yml` configuration just as in the standalone_migrations gem manual. However, when I create a user model:

```
require '../../db/dbconnect'

p ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end

User.new
```

First I get an empty list for the tables and then an exception

```
Could not find table 'users' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

What can I do to make it work?

**EDIT 1:**

My `db/config.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: development.db
  encoding: utf8

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: aquareader.db
  encoding: utf8

test: &test
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: test.db
  encoding: utf8
```

And my `db/dbconnect.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'

# read the connection information from the database config file
dbconfig = YAML::load(File.open(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config.yml')))

# connect to the database
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig['development'])
```

**EDIT 2:**

I found that my `developement.db` table was being create my the migrations in my root folder with the correct tables and everything. However, when I run `lib/myproject/users.rb` it creates a `development.db` in the project directory and doesn't use the one specified in the `dbconnect.rb` file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Which database type(sqlite, mysql..) are you using? Can you verify at the database level if the tables are present? You may be creating the table in one database and connecting to a different database.

Comment: paste your database.yml file

Comment: Hmm.. I suspect something with the naming might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was so obvious that I'm quite ashamed I asked a question here.. All I had to do is set the absolute path to the database file in my `config.yml`.

Comment: Don't be ashamed for that... But can you edit your question with the correction? It could be useful for other people who have a similar problem.

Comment: I answered my question below and I plan to make my answer the accepted one, but I have to wait for two days.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. I suspect something with the naming might be a problem. Rails uses 'magic' to derive the table name from an ActiveRecord class.

Can you show how your tables are actually named in your database with:  `describe tables` or the equivalent for your data store?